# Read data from an excel CSV to an html page and search

Tags: javascript, php, csv

How to load some data from an `CSV file to an html/php page?`.

The CSV file contains the data such as 'username','emailid','phone number'. These three parameters in each row, that should be loaded to an html/php page. Also, I need to write back 'username','emailid','phone number' to excel sheet. Is this can be done?(CSV to HTML page loaded).

And, I need to search each elements, in row-wise.

Comment: It doesn't sound like the most robust infrastructure but it's doable. My advice is to ignore the excel format and save and load all of your spreadsheets as CSV files. these are easily readable with a few lines of code in any language. Make sure the to sanitize your data and save the .csv as UTF-8 if users can append to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert the excel sheet to csv file and then you can do it like this

```
     $handle = fopen("yourexcel.csv",'r');
    if(!$handle) die('Cannot open uploaded file.');

    //Read the file as csv
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        $username = $data['0'];
        $email = $data['1'];
        $phonenumber = $data['2'];

here data[0],data[1] are the columns of the excel sheet

        if(strlen($username ) || strlen($email) || strlen($phonenumber)){

        $query2 = "insert into user_master(username,email,phonenumber) values   ('".$username."','".$email."','".$phonenumber."');";
        mysql_query($query2);
        }
```

Then you can retreive the data from your DB and dipplay in your project where ever you needed

Comment: I tried this code, but doesn't loads data. I don't need any database actions, Is there any other ways to write back excel file, other than this database 'query2'.

Comment: thats fine if you only want to print the data from the excel sheet then convert the file as .csv file which can be seen in save as then in the above code just echo the $username,$email and $phone number you wil get it

Answer (score 1):

i do agree with LcLk that it's not robust way , but yes there are some class available like PHPExcel and excelReader in php by that you can achieve it !!!

do Find the link below

[PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/releases/view/119187)

[ExcelReader](http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/read-excel-file-data-php_pc)